# Pyinstaller executable fails importing torchvision

Tags: python, pytorch, pyinstaller, torchvision

This is my **main.py**:

```py
import torchvision
input("Press key")
```

It runs correctly in the command line: `python main.py`

I need an executable for windows. So I did : `pyinstaller main.py`

But when I launched the **main.exe**, inside `/dist/main` I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>

  ... (omitted)

  File "site-packages\torchvision\ops\misc.py", line 135, in <module>
  File "site-packages\torchvision\ops\misc.py", line 148, in FrozenBatchNorm2d
  File "site-packages\torch\jit\__init__.py", line 850, in script_method
  File "site-packages\torch\jit\frontend.py", line 152, in get_jit_def
  File "inspect.py", line 973, in getsource
  File "inspect.py", line 955, in getsourcelines
  File "inspect.py", line 786, in findsource
OSError: could not get source code
[2836] Failed to execute script main
```

It seems that some source code is not correctly imported from pyinstaller. I am not sure if the problems is the **torch** module or **torchvision**.

Additional info:

- I recently installed Visual Studio 2019

System info:

- Window 10
- Python 3.7
- torch-1.1.0
- torchvision-0.3.0

[EDIT]

I found that the problem is in the definition of the class **FrozenBatchNorm2d** inside torchvision. The following script produce the same error as the one before posted:

**main.py**

```
import torch

class FrozenBatchNorm2d(torch.jit.ScriptModule):

    def __init__(self, n):
        super(FrozenBatchNorm2d, self).__init__()

    @torch.jit.script_method

    def forward(self):
        pass
```

I copied all the torch source file. But I still got the error...

Comment: Have you tried `pyinstaller --hidden-import=torchvision --hidden-import=torch`?

Comment: Yes I tried and doesn't fix the  problem.
However importing only torch works. Torchvision raise the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downgrade **torchvision** to the previous version fix the error.

```
pip uninstall torchvision
pip install torchvision==0.2.2.post3
```

Comment: I won't downvote since this apparently worked for others, but it did not work for me. Curious as to why.

Answer (score 2):

The monkey patch didn't work for me since I had the error when importing torch.jit.

So before importing torch I used the following workaround in my main.py:

```
os.environ["PYTORCH_JIT"] = "0"
```

Obviously you lose the JIT optimization but at least, the executable works.

Comment: I spent HOURS trying everything I could find on a solution to this issue, including all the answers/comments above. This is the only thing that has worked for me. I realize it's not the perfect solution for the reason you yourself note, but it is A solution. Thankyou!

Comment: Happy it could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this monkey patch.

```
def script_method(fn, _rcb=None):
    return fn
def script(obj, optimize=True, _frames_up=0, _rcb=None):
    return obj    
import torch.jit
torch.jit.script_method = script_method 
torch.jit.script = script
```