# Fail in PyInstaller to get source code of TorchScript for windows executable file

Tags: windows, pytorch, pyinstaller

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61756222/pyinstaller-executable-fails-to-get-source-code-of-torchscript), however, the solutions provided for that question did not solve my problem.

I am using:

- torch                     1.5.1+cpu
- torchvision               0.6.1+cpu
- pyinstaller               4.0
- pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2020.7

I ran various commands for Pyinstaller but none of them worked.

Please give any information that may help to solve this problem.
Thank you.

```
d:\add_yolov3\env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:493: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "torch\_utils_internal.py", line 46, in get_source_lines_and_file
    filename = None  # in case getsourcefile throws
  File "inspect.py", line 955, in getsourcelines
  File "inspect.py", line 786, in findsource
OSError: could not get source code

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "d:\add_yolov3\env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "gui\guiUtils.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "d:\add_yolov3\env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "detect.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "d:\add_yolov3\env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "models.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "d:\add_yolov3\env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "utils\utils.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "d:\add_yolov3\env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "torchvision\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "d:\add_yolov3\env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "torchvision\models\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "d:\add_yolov3\env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "torchvision\models\detection\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "d:\add_yolov3\env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "torchvision\models\detection\faster_rcnn.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "d:\add_yolov3\env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "torchvision\ops\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "d:\add_yolov3\env\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "torchvision\ops\poolers.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "torch\jit\__init__.py", line 1280, in script
    _compile_and_register_class(obj, _rcb, qualified_name)
  File "torch\jit\__init__.py", line 1107, in _compile_and_register_class
    ast = get_jit_class_def(obj, obj.__name__)
  File "torch\jit\frontend.py", line 152, in get_jit_class_def
    self_name=self_name) for method in methods]
  File "torch\jit\frontend.py", line 152, in <listcomp>
    self_name=self_name) for method in methods]
  File "torch\jit\frontend.py", line 164, in get_jit_def
    sourcelines, file_lineno, filename = get_source_lines_and_file(fn, torch._C.ErrorReport.call_stack())
  File "torch\_utils_internal.py", line 53, in get_source_lines_and_file
    print('obj:\t', obj)
OSError: Can't get source for <function LevelMapper.__call__ at 0x000001A8DF403708>. TorchScript requires source access in order to carry out compilation, make sure original .py files are available. Original error: could not get source code
[11512] Failed to execute script main
```